# Using ModelBuilder to iterate row and calculate field (code block)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, field-calculator, iterator

I would like to use "iterate row selection in ModelBuilder" and for each row, I want to use the field calculator's code block to create a conditional statement that goes:

If field=0 then go to the next row.

if field=1, go back to the previous row and assign the field with a new value based on an equation, then stop.

Comment: You can't do that in modelbuilder, iterators move forwards never backwards. This sort of logic can only be done with python scripting and using a combination of search cursors and possibly dictionaries.